# How to use my ML model on my Django RestFramework?

Tags: machine-learning, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is basically my whole project. I have got the django server ready and the model as well. I need to know how to integrate it so the flow of my project could be like:
a)User takes or uploads an image on Android app.
b)The image taken goes to the Android Table on my server as an encoded64 bit image string.
c) The image is then processed by the ML model and which will send the result (which will be a label) back so the person can view the label of the dish.
Am I going in the right direction? If not what should I do?
Help needed. Thank you.

The current setup was working but now it just gives an error:

**argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'ListSerializer'**

**Models.py**

```
class Food(models.Model):
label=models.TextField(max_length=200)
link = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False)
 Image = models.TextField(link, null=True)

class Android(models.Model):
label=models.TextField(max_length=200)
imagestring=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)  //convert this to Image
```

**Serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Server,Android
from api import Code
from  habibi import  readb64 as decode
from  habibi import  main as m

class AndroidSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
return_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
class Meta:
    model = Android
    fields = ('label', 'imagestring','return_image')

def get_return_image(self, value):
    queryset = Android.objects.filter(imagestring=value.imagestring)
    queryset_serializer = AndroidSerializers(queryset, many=True, read_only=True)
    a = decode(queryset_serializer)
    b = m(a)
    c = Code.predicet(b)
    return c


class FoodSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=Server
    fields=('url','label','Image','link')
```

**Views**

```
class FoodViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Server.objects.all()
serializer_class =FoodSerializers


class Androids(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset =Android.objects.all()
serializer_class = AndroidSerializers
```

**Code.py(prediction)**

```
  from sklearn import preprocessing
  import numpy as np 
  from sklearn.externals import joblib
  def predicet(b):
 seed = 7
 np.random.seed(seed)

Y = ['Club Sandwich', 'Onion Ring', 'Pizza']

encodedvalue = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded_y = encodedvalue.fit_transform(Y)
clf = joblib.load('D:\csvs\models\pridictionmodel.pkl')
y_pred = clf.predict(b)
haaha = encodedvalue.inverse_transform(y_pred)
return  haaha
```

**Habibi.py(Feature)**

```
import cv2
import math as m
import base64
from PIL import Image
import cv2
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np



def Applysift(img):
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
x = np.array(des)

y = x[:500, :]

j = y.flatten()


return j



 def GetIntensity(img):
  h, w, c = np.shape(img)
  height=h-2
  widht=w-2
  blue = img.item(height, widht, 0)
  green = img.item(height, widht, 1)
 red = img.item(height, widht, 2)
 inte=((0.2126*red) + (0.7152*green) + (0.0722*blue))

 uper = m.ceil(inte)

 return uper



 def average_hash(image, hash_size=8):

 im_pil = Image.fromarray(image)
 img = im_pil.convert('L').resize((hash_size, hash_size),Image.ANTIALIAS)
 pixels = np.array(img.getdata()).reshape((hash_size, hash_size))
 avg = pixels.mean()
 diff = pixels > avg
 // make a hash
 return diff



def binary_array_to_hex(arr):
h = 0
s = []
for i,v in enumerate(arr.flatten()):
    if v: h += 2**(i % 8)
    if (i % 8) == 7:
        s.append(hex(h)[2:].rjust(2, '0'))
        h = 0
return "".join(s)


  def hex_to_int(hexval):
  return int(hexval,16)





def readb64(base64_string):
sbuf = StringIO()
sbuf.write(base64.b64decode(base64_string))
pimg = Image.open(sbuf)
return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pimg), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)


def main(a):
#links of image

j=a
#img1 = cv2.imread(j)
img = cv2.imread(j, -1)
sift = Applysift(img)
intensity = GetIntensity(img)
hash = average_hash(img)
arr = hash * 1
hexval = binary_array_to_hex(arr)
intval = hex_to_int(hexval)
orb_List = np.array(sift).tolist()
orb_List.insert(0, intensity)
orb_List.insert(1, intval)
feature = np.array(orb_List)

#df = pd.DataFrame(feature)
#dff = df.T
return feature
```

Comment: Does the current setup work? You should add that to your question so it will be clear if you're asking for how to optimize it or how to fix resulting bugs

Comment: Updated..need help

Comment: That error should be from this line a = decode(queryset_serializer). 
Why do you need to pass a serializer to the decoder? you should just pass value.imagestring.

Comment: So that i can decode the imagestring to an image

Comment: That is what the decode function does right? so you should be passing the imagestring to it and not a serializer like I said above. `decode(value.imagestring)`

Comment: i see now imma try it as soon as i get free from the class .other than that what more changes  should i do ?

Comment: First, try to format the post correctly because it's difficult to read the code

Comment: Another advice is to store the prediction in the model, so you won't have to run the prediction algorithm each time the image is being retrieved. You can store it the first time the Android object is created